# How to parse a HAProxy config file in Java

Tags: java, haproxy

Currently I'm using Properties.java to parse my haproxy.cfg as follows:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new StringReader(configFileContents));
```

But when I print it out, I see that except for a few entries like

```
{
 user=haproxy,
 log=global,
 retries=3
}
```

all the others are incorrectly mapped/parsed. Properties.java probably isn't the right parser for HAProxy config files. So please suggest a suitable one.

Comment: Can you post the whole config file? @curious_george

Comment: It's the same as this one https://gist.github.com/flores/1623381 but with different values. @cunnniemm